# JointJS: the best method for doing a transition in both x and y?

Tags: transition, jointjs

I'm animating an element's motion to a desired new point, but I have not been able to work out the proper syntax to pass the transition function two values. I have a workaround right now:

```
packet.transition('position/y', linkInfo.end.y, {
    delay: animationDelay,
    duration: animationDuration
});

packet.transition('position/x', linkInfo.end.x, {
    delay: animationDelay,
    duration: animationDuration
});
```

That seems less than satisfactory as I know there has to be a better way. I've spent too long poring over the docs and tutorials and the correct method still isn't penetrating my thick skull. Can some kind soul help out?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the code I ended up using. My problem was not understanding the interpolation types.

```
var linkInfo = {
    start: {
        x: startX,
        y: startY
    },
    end: {
        x: endX,
        y: endY         
    },
    source: sourceCell,
    target: targetCell
};


packet.position(linkInfo.start.x, linkInfo.start.y);

graph.addCell(packet);

packet.transition('position', linkInfo.end, { 
    delay: animationDelay, 
    duration: animationDuration, 
    valueFunction: joint.util.interpolate.object
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try something like this:

```
packet.transition('position', {x: linkInfo.end.y, y: linkInfo.end.y}, {
    delay: animationDelay,
    duration: animationDuration
});
```

Comment: Yes, Andry, I ended up doing something very similar. My problem was not understanding the proper use of the interpolation types. Many thanks for responding!